# How can I extrapolate the reversed hex string with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, nfc

through flutter I am reading a series of beacons with nfc_manager, the string I read is the one reported in the log below, how can I extrapolate the reversed hex string to be able to print it from the string represents in the log?

**Flutter Code:**

```
NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
          log(tag.data.toString());
 

        });
```

**Log print:**

```
    {nfca: {identifier: [4, 7, 255, 82, 190, 78, 129], atqa: [68, 0], 
maxTransceiveLength: 253, sak: 0, timeout: 618}, 
mifareultralight: {identifier: [4, 7, 255, 82, 190, 78, 129],
 maxTransceiveLength: 253, timeout: 618, type: 1}, ndefformatable: {identifier: [4, 7, 255, 82, 190, 78, 129]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Decode the json string like

```
var convert =  json.decode(tag.data.toString());
```

Then you can use `String.fromCharCodes` like the following

```
List<int> charCodes = convert['nfca']['identifier'];
print(new String.fromCharCodes(charCodes));
```

Comment: how con add this code to tag.data

Comment: Your solution prints blank

Comment: Error is: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
{nfca: {identifier: [4, 7, 255, 82, 190, 78, 129], atqa: [68, 0], maxTransc...
 ^

Comment: Pls write the full error message

Comment: this is error message full: : Unexpected character (at character 2) {nfca: {identifier: [4, 7, 255, 82, 190, 78, 129], atqa: [68, 0], maxTransc

Comment: Try List<int> charCodes = log.data.nfca.identifier; without the json decode code.